# How to redirect HTTP to HTTPS on Elastic Beanstalk Single Instance Environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Spring Boot web application deployed in Elastic Beanstalk single instance environment using Amazon Linux 2. I have configured SSL in the NGNIX as per the documentation and all HTTPS request are working fine.
However the HTTP requests are not redirected to HTTPS.
Below is my conf file located at **`\PROJECT_ROOT\.platform\nginx\conf.d\https.conf`**

```
# HTTP server
server {
    listen 80;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

# HTTPS server
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate      /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key;
    
    ssl_session_timeout  5m;
    
    ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;
    
    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_set_header   Connection "";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    }
}
```

I have created an **A record** to map `example.com` to EB environment URL.

However, when I try to hit `http://example.com` it simply loads the homepage over HTTP rather then redirecting to HTTPS.

Can someone please help me with this ?

Comment: Can you ssh to the EB instance and manually edit nginx, to verify that your new configuration is actually correct?

Comment: I did, I can see the same conf in /etc/nginx/conf.d/https.conf.
The thing I wonder is how port 80 is serving my app because I have not defined a port 80 listener to prox to my springboot server.

Comment: Okay I found the issue, the nginx.conf file has a default server listening on port 80 which is defined after my custom conf causing this issue, I manually removed that server section and now it is working fine, but not sure how to preserve it as once I do a deployment it will again override my changes.

Comment: You may need to fully overwrite nginx. So instead of using `.platform\nginx\conf.d\https.conf`, perform full overwrite with `.platform/nginx/nginx.conf`.

Comment: Doesn't this seems to be an overkill just for a simple redirection rule we are required to override the whole conf rather than extending. Is there supposedly a more elegant solution?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do it the other way. You can wait more, and maybe some will provide simpler way in answers.

Comment: Are you behind a Load Balancer or disabled? If you are behind a load balancer, it's more tricky than just watching the port ,)

Comment: No, it's a single instance environment with no load balancer